# Who drowned in the beached ship?

Tags: character, dunkirk

After the beached ship in *Dunkirk* floats out into the sea the soldiers leave the ship as it sinks but one doesn't manage to escape and drowns. Which of the soldiers was it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Gibson

> As the ship sinks, **Gibson gets tangled in a chain and drowns**.
>
> Alex and Tommy swim for a nearby minesweeper, but it is sunk by a German bomber. Mr Dawson's boat arrives on the scene and takes them on board. They return to England, where Alex expects their disgraceful retreat will earn them the scorn of the British public; instead, they receive a heroes' welcome.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkirk_(2017_film)#ii._The_Sea)</sup>